# Trying to simulate point patterns via simulate.mppm causes error

Tags: r, spatstat

I am trying to simulate a point pattern based on a model fit to a dataset of several multitype point patterns. However, I can't run simulate.mppm without raising an error. I attached the code below (using `optimbase_1.0-9` and `spatstat_1.62-2`):

```
library(spatstat)
library(optimbase)
flusubset <- flu[1:4]
typelist <- lapply(lapply(flusubset$pattern, marks), levels)
num_marks <- length(typelist[[1]])
iradii <- 50*ones(num_marks,num_marks)
hradii <- 3*ones(num_marks,num_marks)
Int <- anylist()
for (i in 1:dim(flusubset)[1]) {
  Int[[i]] <- MultiStraussHard(iradii=iradii, hradii=hradii)
}
Int <- as.hyperframe(Int)
multmodel <- mppm(pattern ~ 1, data=flusubset, interaction=Int)
simulate(multmodel)
```

Whenever I run this code, I encounter the error:

```
Error in check.nvector(w, nrow(x), things = "rows of x") : The length of ‘w’ (=16744) should equal the number of rows of x (=15424)
9. stop(whinge)
8. check.nvector(w, nrow(x), things = "rows of x")
7. sumouter(mom, lam * wt * glmsub)
6. vcmGibbs(object, ..., what = what, err = err)
5. vcov.mppm(object, what = "fisher", err = "null")
4. vcov(object, what = "fisher", err = "null")
3. subfits(object)
2. simulate.mppm(multmodel)
1. simulate(multmodel)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in current versions of `spatstat`.

I have fixed it in the development version `spatstat 1.62-2.011` available from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat). The next public release of `spatstat` containing the bug fix will be in February 2020.

For bugs in `spatstat`, please post an Issue on the issues page at the GitHub repository.